# devtools::build_vignettes yields "Error : invalid version specification 'pandoc.exe 1.13.1'

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, devtools

After upgrading R to 3.1.2 and updating all packages I can no longer build vignettes.

```
devtools::build_vignettes(shdoe)
```

The output is as follows:

```
Building shdoe vignettes
Error : invalid version specification 'pandoc.exe 1.13.1'
Warning in engine$weave(file, quiet = quiet) :
  Pandoc is not available. Please install Pandoc.
Moving shdoe-intro.html, shdoe-intro.R to inst/doc/
Copying shdoe-intro.Rmd to inst/doc/
```

This is after an update of pandoc from version 1.12.x (which yielded the same error). My OS is windows 7, and Pandoc is on the PATH.

Comment: The error I get (after `R CMD build <pkgname>`) after not finding pandoc is `Error: processing vignette 'translate_gen.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
object 'pb' not found`. According to the source of knitr, `pb` seems to come from [output.R](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/output.R). Can you `pandoc /?`? I get an error `pandoc: /R: openFile: permission denied (Permission denied).`

Comment: Note also that this happened to me for pandoc 1.9.1.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is associated with the way knitr parses the version number returned by

```
pandoc.exe --version
```

which includes the name by which pandoc is called:

```
pandoc.exe 1.13.1
[...]
```

On windows, `R`'s `Sys.which('pandoc')` which is used by `knitr` to get pandoc's executable yields `<PATH TO PANDOC>\pandoc.exe`, leading to the above call to get pandoc's version which then cannot be handled correctly by `knitr`.

The [faulty code](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/7bb9623ee2eb9ec3da45169243e6e3721aa7555f#diff-c8795a369c7e2d81584077a307d2ba3e) was introduced in `knitr` version 1.7 (before it used `rmarkdown::pandoc_available()` to check the availablilty of pandoc).

A workaround is to set the system variable `RSTUDIO_PANDOC` to `<PATH TO PANDOC>` (since `knitr` regards its presence sufficient).

Comment: Thanks. It should be fixed in the development version now.